# how to joining two group-by queries

Tags: ms-access, group-by

alright this is my mistakes, I asked question that nobody would understand it, now I'm trying to make my question clearer and more simple.

Here I've 3 tables, first is employeeid contains (nameid, salary), second is overtimeid contains (nameid 'from employeeid', period, tot_ot), and the third is absenceid contains (nameid 'from employeeid', period, tot_absence).

how can I populate those three tables into one query containing (nameid, salary, period (fr overtimeid should be the same with absenceid), tot_ot, tot_absence).

please help me master of ms-access, I can't do wonder thing without your help,..... thanks before.

Comment: You attached results of queries, please post here queries design and what do you expect from resulting query

Comment: @SergeyS. I've edit my question, to make sure it's really meets your need

Comment: @SergeyS. I've revised my questions, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query like this:

```
SELECT nameid, period, Sum(tot_absence) AS SumOftot_absence, Sum(tot_ot) AS SumOftot_ot
FROM
    (SELECT nameid, period, tot_absence, Null AS tot_ot
    FROM absenceid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nameid, period, Null AS tot_absence, tot_ot
    FROM  overtimeid)
GROUP BY nameid, period;
```

Then outer join it with `employeeid` and you will receive the list of employees for each period

**Edit**

Query for tables from comments:

```
SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, sum(JMLMBUR) as sumofJMLMBUR, sum(TOTABS) as sumofTOTABS, sum(KASBON) as sumofKASBON
FROM (
    SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, JMLMBUR, Null as TOTABS, Null as KASBON
    FROM overtimeid
    Union ALL
    SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, Null as JMLMBUR, TOTABS, KASBON
    FROM potonganid
    )
GROUP BY NMKARY, PERIODGJ;
```

Comment: thanks, code works just fine. if I want to add more detail more column to sum, (maybe 'FROM UNION' code) I don't know how to do that I paste the code that isn't work 'SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, sum(JMLMBUR) as sumofJMLMBUR, sum(TOTABS) as sumofTOTABS, sum(KASBON) as sumofKASBON
FROM
          (SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, JMLMBUR, Null as TOTABS from overtimeid
           UNION ALL
           SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, Null as JMLMBUR, TOTABS from potonganid
           UNION ALL
           SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, JMLMBUR, TOTABS, Null as KASBON from overtimeid)
GROUP BY NMKARY, PERIODGJ;'

Comment: Quantity and type of all columns in all union queries should be the same. Union query is like a table. You are trying to select 5 columns from union query with 4 columns (quantity and column names in union query defined by first query). Add NULL column to first two queries.

Comment: sorry, the way your explanation is above my knowledge (crying) please make it simple, once again sorry to make you feel annoying

Comment: If you want to select 5 fields, all 4 SELECTs should have 5 fields, you have 4 fields in two queries. I'd recommend to read syntax of UNION queries.

Comment: Oo,.. plz mr. sergey you now your knowledge won't wasted. I still don't get it. problem is 1) I don't know to add 'Null As' command 2) I don't know to add more sum column, more than 2 sum column,... please,... please,.... I'll note this lesson

Comment: In which table located KASBON field?

Comment: KASBON is in absenceid tables, plz sir,.. help me on this

Comment: `SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, Sum(TOTABS) AS SumOfTOTABS, Sum(KASBON) AS SumOfKASBON, Sum(JMLMBUR) AS SumofJMLMBUR
FROM
     (SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, TOTABS, KASBON, Null As JMLMBUR
     FROM potonganid
     UNION ALL
     SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, Null As TOTABS, KASBON, JMLMBUR
     FROM potonganid
     UNION ALL
     SELECT NMKARY, PERIODGJ, TOTABS, Null As KASBON, JMLMBUR
     FROM  overtimeid)
GROUP BY NMKARY, PERIODGJ;`

Comment: Updated. If something don't work, try to run each query of union block separately first.

Comment: this is my big mistakes while good teacher teach me, really sorry KASBON is not in absenceid fields it's actually in one fields with TOTABS which is potonganid, sorry,... sorry,... no wonder it's error.

Comment: Try this variant then